# Django TypeError at /account/register/ 'tuple' object is not callable

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-class-based-views

Issue Description

1 -here i am trying to render two forms with their fields on a wizard. User fields and Profile fields (on a OneToOne relationship).
the end game is to complete profile and User data on account signup.
Now i have managed to achieve this which similar variations of the code in the views. the real issue lies with below

2- The images will not save to the database upon account creation. Please know i have done the following
- set up media root options in the settings and main site urls
-images also save to media room from the django admin, but i believe that functionality is specifically related to the models i have created

my template is fairly large with the bootstrap elements included to i would not add it however it is set up to render specific fields from the two forms

There is an error with my views

## My Views

```
class RegisterView(CreateView):
    model = User, UserProfile
    form_class = RegistrationForm, UserProfileForm

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_form = RegistrationForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()
            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user
            if 'profile_photo' in request.FILES:
                profile.profile_photo = request.FILES['profile_photo']
                profile.save()
                registered = True
            else:
                print(user_form.errors, profile_form.errors)
        else:
            user_form = RegistrationForm()
            profile_form = UserProfileForm()

        return render(request, 'accounts/registration.html',
                      {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form, 
        'registered': registered})
```

## my urls

```
 path('register/', RegisterView.as_view(), name='register'),
```

## TraceBack

> File "C:\Users\Rashid
>   Thompson\Desktop\workspace\python\django\sal1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py"
>   in inner 35. response = get_response(request)
>
> File "C:\Users\Rashid
>   Thompson\Desktop\workspace\python\django\sal1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response 128. response =
>   self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File "C:\Users\Rashid
>   Thompson\Desktop\workspace\python\django\sal1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response 126. response = wrapped_callback(request,
>   *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\Rashid
>   Thompson\Desktop\workspace\python\django\sal1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py"
>   in view 69. return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\Rashid
>   Thompson\Desktop\workspace\python\django\sal1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py"
>   in dispatch 89. return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\Rashid
>   Thompson\Desktop\workspace\python\django\sal1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py"
>   in get 168. return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\Rashid
>   Thompson\Desktop\workspace\python\django\sal1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py"
>   in get 133. return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())
>
> File "C:\Users\Rashid
>   Thompson\Desktop\workspace\python\django\sal1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py"
>   in get_context_data 66. kwargs['form'] = self.get_form()
>
> File "C:\Users\Rashid
>   Thompson\Desktop\workspace\python\django\sal1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py"
>   in get_form 33. return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
>
> Exception Type: TypeError at /account/register/ Exception Value:
>   'tuple' object is not callable

Comment: This isn't how generic views work. You can't specify two forms and two models and expect the view to know what to do. Since you have already overridden the post method, you should probably do the same with the get method and not bother inheriting from CreateView at all.

Comment: relatively new to django, could you please provide a snippet ?